# i want to iterate through a table rows to get data but it only pick up the first row repeatedly, don't know where is the mistake?

Tags: php

```
<?php
       include_once("simple_html_dom.php");

    //this is the main function to extract data from a table 
    function ScrapeAndSave($url,$i)
    {
        $city_id = $i;
      //echo $city_id; exit;
        $html = file_get_html($url);

        //echo $html;exit;

        // below you will write the code to extract data from above $html object    

       foreach($html->find('table[class=cart]') as $company){
           //$keeper = array();

         // echo $company;exit;
          for ($i=2; $i<=3; $i++) { 

           //echo $product_name;exit;
           $url = $company->find('tr[$i] th a')[0]->href;
           //echo $url;exit;
           $pos = strripos($url, "=");
           $product_id = substr($url, $pos+1);
           //echo $product_id;exit;
           $product_name = $company->find('tr[$i] th a')[0]->plaintext;
           //echo $product_name;exit;
           $min = $company->find('tr[$i] td[class=pricedata]')[1]->plaintext;
           //echo $min;exit;
           $max = $company->find('tr[$i] td[class=pricedata]')[2]->plaintext;
           //echo $mix;
           $avg = $company->find('tr[$i] td[class=pricedata]')[3]->plaintext;

            $result = "INSERT INTO product_prices (c_id,pr_id, min, max, average) VALUES ('$city_id','$product_id','$min', '$max', '$avg')"; 
            $status = mysqli_query($con,$result);

            if($status == false)
            {
                echo "<script>
            alert('something went wrong, please try again');
            </script>";

                } else {
                        echo "<script>
            alert('data successfully entered into the database');
                    </script>";

            }
       }
     }      

    }
    //this is the full loop to get data for one city

    for($i = 1; $i<=1; $i++){
          $url = "http://url".$i;
          ScrapeAndSave($url,$i);
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: for($i = 1; $i<=1; $i++) this loop run only one time. check this loop adding echo or print_r

Comment: How many tables does the HTML contains and how many rows do they have? Your loops seem odd.

Comment: `for ($i=2; $i<=3; $i++)` this loop will only parse one row too.

Comment: @GrecoJonathan That will parse two rows.

Comment: The problem is not about the loop in my opinion, but the single quote combined with `$i` which not working

Answer (score 0):

You have a quotes problem

`$url = $company->find('tr[$i] th a')`

Is not working and probably return the first element available.

because simple quotes does not allow PHP to parse `$i` as a variable but as a string.

To fix that use doubles quotes, like this :

`$url = $company->find("tr[{$i}] th a")`

Of course do this for all of your `find` calls

Comment: thank you, i find out that problem was in selection of rows, which is solved but now it give me this error.Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraping\get_prices.php on line 12

Notice: Trying to get property 'href' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraping\get_prices.php on line 12

Comment: foreach ($html->find('table[class=cart] tr') as $row) { 
         $url = $row->find('th[class=listItem] a')[0]->href;
         echo $url;exit;
         $pos = strripos($url, "=");
         $product_id = substr($url, $pos+1);
         $product_name = $row->find('th[class=listItem] a')[0]->plaintext;
         
              $min = $row->find('td[class=pricedata]')[1]->plaintext;
               $max = $row->find('td[class=pricedata]')[2]->plaintext;
               $avg = $row->find('td[class=pricedata]')[3]->plaintext;

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraping\get_prices.php on line 12